# Communicating with an XBee module using Java

Tags: java, xbee

I want to connect my xbee-api-0.9 module Java and communicate with it by sending AT commands.

```
import com.rapplogic.xbee.api.XBee;
import com.rapplogic.xbee.api.XBeeException;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class Xbee_1 {
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Xbee_1.class);
    public static void main( String []args){
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        XBee xbee = new XBee();
        try {
            xbee.open("COM34", 9600);
        } catch (XBeeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("nepeut pas s'ouvr");
        }
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: this question is rather unspecific. please provide code/environment details...

Comment: I want to to post an image but i can't because the reputation. can you give me a solution to this ??

Comment: I want receive information from arduino using Xbee to java

Comment: please update your question instead.

Comment: explain problem you are facing??

Answer (score 1):

Digi has an [Open Source Java library](https://github.com/digidotcom/XBeeJavaLibrary) to interface with their XBee modules.  It was [announced](http://www.digi.com/blog/community/official-xbee-java-library/) earlier this year.  I suggest that you use that as your starting point.

> Creating XBee applications just got way easier. Gone are the days of
>   toiling away for every inch of code. In order to make it as simple as
>   possible for you to write applications that interact with XBee, we
>   have created the XBee Java Library. This library supports ZigBee,
>   802.15.4, DigiMesh and Point-to-Multipoint XBee devices!